# Why I can't establish http connection from flutter app and .NET Core Web API

Tags: android, flutter, dart, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm building application with `.NET` Core WEB API as a backend, and `flutter` as a frontend.

The `backend API` is up and running, but I have problems establishing `http connection` from the flutter app. My goal is to login a user. Here is my approach:

Request that is being send to the backend:

```
class LoginRequest {
  final String usernameOrEmail;
  final String password;

  LoginRequest({required this.usernameOrEmail, required this.password});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'usernameOrEmail': usernameOrEmail,
      'password': password,
    };
  }
}
```

Service abstraction(interface):

```
import 'package:frontend/requests/login_request.dart';

abstract class UserService {
  Future<bool> login(LoginRequest request);
}
```

Service implementation:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:frontend/requests/login_request.dart';
import 'package:frontend/services/abstractions/user_service.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
  @override
  Future<bool> login(LoginRequest request) async {
    try {
      var response = await http.post(
          Uri.http("127.0.0.1:5224", "/api/User/login"),
          body: jsonEncode(request.toJson()));
      var body = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm also using `GetIt` dependency injection provider, and it's working properly. I have a simple button that triggers login function of the service.

While my backend API is up and running in debug mode, I tried to establish the connection on various ways, but it seems that none of them works.

I tried `http/https` based on `launchSettings.json` on backend.

I created firewall rules to enable the ports.

I tried localhost, `127.0.0.1`, and (strange, found it on internet) `10.0.2.2.`

On `10.0.2.2` the request throws no errors, but, the response body is empty string, not what I'm expecting to see.

The error I get (among others) is:

```
OSError (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111).
```

Any help will be welcomed. Thanks :)

Comment: You did not tell where your server is running. You did not tell where your app is running. So we dont know your setup.

Comment: @blackapps It's full development environment. The server(web api) is running in debug on localhost:5224(http) and localhost:7012(https). The flutter app is in debug also.

Comment: Localhost? Every device is is its own localhost. Your Android device is its own localhost. Every pc is its own localhost.

Comment: You did not in any way tell your setup. You even did not tell where your Android app is running. On an Android device? On an emulator? What is your setup,?

Comment: @blackapps the android app is running on a emulator(Pixel 3a API 34 extension level 7 x86 64 emulator-5556- mobile)

Comment: I asked for more info. Please give complete setup.

Comment: @blackapps Well, I'm very new to mobile development. I do not know what else can I share :)

Comment: We still dont know where your server is running. As localhost tells us nothing.

Comment: @blackapps well it's running on the same development machine as the flutter app(and emulator)

Comment: Ok. Glad you told that emulator is on same machine. Now you complained about http. But you also mentioned https. Can you use that https with your Android app?

Comment: @blackapps When I use https I get: Handshake error in client. Because of that, instead I target the same api on http(just different port) and the response.body is an empty string, and also the request never made to the backend on the first place(I have a breakpoint)

Comment: Did you enable clear text traffic in application tag in manifest file?

Comment: @blackapps I didn't edit the Manifest file. Am I missing something?

Comment: I fould the solution. I will post it as an answer, and accept it ! Thank you for your time :)